# Google Sheets - Apply a link to multiple cells, or a whole row

Tags: google-sheets

How can I apply a link to multiple cells, or a whole row - in Google Sheets.
For example, on my sheet I have 50 rows with data in columns A-F.
I want the user to be able to click any cell in each row and get taken to the same link destination.
But I don't want to apply the link each time separately for each cell.  (AS far as I can see, I can only apply a link to one cell). So I would have to apply the same link for each cell in the row.

This is not to be confused with applying multiple links in one cell.
I want to apply one link to multiple cells (that are consecutive i.e. row 5, columns A-E).

Comment: Are you cells empty? In that case, dragging works in my phone's sheet app. Doesn't it work in desktop?

Comment: No, my cells are not empty.  They are filled with data.  But I tried it as per your suggestion with empty cells, and it just fills one cell (the most left cell) with text (the name of the link I am pointing to.  But the link is only in 1 cell.   Yes, I am in desktop.

Comment: Assuming you have cells filled from A1 to E5, I would take another sheet and use `=HYPERLINK("url", FirstSheet!A1)` in A1 and then drag till E5.

Comment: To use in some other space in the same sheet, the formula would be else depending on the scenario.

Comment: The other option is using Apps Script. You won't need another sheet if you use Apps Script. Haven't tried Apps Script once in a while but seems like it would be like that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I really appreciate it, but these are bit complex (for me at least).  I guess I am asking for confirmation that I am not missing something obvious and easy - and your answer confirms that.  I'm shocked that something so simple, cannot be done so simply.